# OS X Mavericks compatibility with R

Tags: r, osx-mavericks

I just upgraded to OS X Mavericks. I'm having errors that are causing R to crash: (using R version 3.0.1):

```
Error in by.default(G1$Y, G1$Subject, mean) : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7c0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Any one facing this issue?

Comment: On the assumption that this error didn't cause a segfault in your previous OSX version (but same R version), best to post to the r-sig-mac mailing list.  I'm sure Simon will be getting a ton of Maverick-related questions :-(

Comment: Same with me. Even forgetting to specify an argument leads to R crashing, which didn't happen before.

Answer (score 4):

I just resolved this issue by upgrading R version to 3.0.2. It looks like Mavericks memory optimization causes serious crashing with R version prior to 3.0.2. So try to upgrade it and report back if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Note also that llvm-4.2 is not in XCode 5 so if you update to the latest version you may be in uncharted territory. The R Core has been hesitant to go all-in with the Apple-way as far as compiler strategy.

Comment: I had serious and random crashes with R 3.0 or 3.0.1, which were fixed with 3.0.2, as well. Random things like typing 'ls' (I meant 'ls()' but messed up) would cause crashes before installing 3.0.2. Since then, everything has worked, though it does seem that updating binary packages may be a bit slower than usual.

Comment: @Wayne: seems to have fixed the crash issues, so far